# Proxy support in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, proxy, webclient

I'm running the following code to check for updates in my software, and I wonder whether VB.Net will automatically user computer proxy settings:

```
Dim CurrentVersion As String = (New System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("URL/version.txt")
```

If not, how can I adapt it to use proxy settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, using

```
Dim UpdateClient As New System.Net.WebClient
UpdateClient.Proxy = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
Dim CurrentVersion As String = UpdateClient.DownloadString("URL/version.txt")
```

is perfectly functional.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding the following settings to your application's app.config file:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using an app.config file?

Comment: yes, HttpWebRequest.Proxy, but may I ask what kind of proxy are you using? SOCKS proxies are not supported

Comment: Don't really know, I'm using my app without any proxy, but users asked me to add proxy support.